# Selecting across tables excluding first and last row of joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are two tables *Session* and *View* where a session may contain many views:

```
Session    
id | app | other_columns
------------------
1  | A   | text
2  | A   | text

View    
id | session | name |   start    |     end
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | A    | 1395221810 | 1395221836
2  | 1       | B    | 1395221837 | 1395221945
3  | 1       | A    | 1395221846 | 1395221998
4  | 2       | A    | 1392241521 | 1392241563
5  | 2       | G    | 1392241564 | 1392241565
6  | 2       | F    | 1392241566 | 1392241579
7  | 2       | I    | 1392241580 | 1392241596
8  | 2       | J    | 1392241596 | 1392241612
```

Now I'd like to get the average length of all sessions (calculated from the sum of *end* - *start* for each view belonging to a session) where app='A', excluding the first and last view (i.e. row) for each session. In the example above, views 1+3 (belonging to session 1) and 4+8 (session 2) should be excluded from the calculation.

The statement I started with looks like this, but obviously, it doesn't incorporate the first+last row-exclusion:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(v.end - v.start)
FROM
    View AS v
        JOIN
    Session AS s ON s.ID = v.session
WHERE
    s.app = 'A';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(id) as max_id, min(id) as min_id, session
from view
group by sesion;
```

id's to be excluded.

```
select * 
from view
     left join (select max(id) as max_id, min(id) as min_id, session
                from view
                group by sesion) exclude ON view.session=exclude.session 
                     AND (view.id=exclude.min_id or view.id=exclude.max_id)
having exclude.session is null;
```

view data without excluded id's

```
select session, avg(end-start) from (
    select * 
    from view
         left join (select max(id) as max_id, min(id) as min_id, session
                    from view
                    group by sesion) exclude ON view.session=exclude.session 
                         AND (view.id=exclude.min_id or view.id=exclude.max_id)
    having exclude.session is null) pure_data
group by session
```

average data

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which looks quite promising! Using this query, I keep getting the error saying "Duplicate column name 'session'". In addition, I'd like to limit the result set to sessions which have app='A'.

Comment: It measn there are 2 columns with name **session**. Just add {alial}.session. You can add the app='A' to the queries

Comment: But in order to include the app, I'd have to do another join, right (because in your example the Session table is not used)?

Comment: yes. just add the JOIN session s ON s.ID = v.session ... WHERE s.app = 'A'